# C++ bitset reference

Tags: c++, c++11, std-bitset

Two questions on bitset reference:

Q1. Is there any way we can return a class private member bitset? 
In the code snippet below (followed by output), I experimented with the regular reference but it won't even modify the bitset member in Foo class.

Q2. From the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307261/bitset-reference), I understand that regular references do not have enough granularity to point to the single bit stored in `bitset` since `bitset` stores them in a more compact form. However, if this is true, how could my code still manage to modify the first bit in b3 in the line `b3[1] = 0`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

class Foo 
{ 
private:
    bitset<4> b1;  
public:
    inline void print_value() 
    {
        cout << "The bitset b1 is: ( "<< b1 << " )" << endl;
    }
    inline void set_all() { b1.set(); }
    inline bitset<4> get_b1() { return b1; }
    inline bitset<4>& get_b1_ref() { return b1; }
}; 

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.print_value();
    f.set_all();
    f.print_value();
    auto b2 = f.get_b1();
    b2.flip();
    cout << "The bitset b2 is: ( "<< b2 << " )" << endl;
    f.print_value();
    auto b3 = f.get_b1_ref();
    cout << "The bitset b3 is: ( "<< b3 << " )" << endl;
    cout << "b3[0] is ( " << b3[0] << " )"<< endl;
    cout << "b3[0] is ( " << b3[1] << " )"<< endl;
    b3[1] = 0;
    cout << "The bitset b3 after change is: ( "<< b3 << " )" << endl;
    f.print_value();
}

Output:
The bitset b1 is: ( 0000 )
The bitset b1 is: ( 1111 )
The bitset b2 is: ( 0000 )
The bitset b1 is: ( 1111 )
The bitset b3 is: ( 1111 )
b3[0] is ( 1 )
b3[0] is ( 1 )
The bitset b3 after change is: ( 1101 )
The bitset b1 is: ( 1111 )
```

Comment: A rule of thumb: "`auto` is never a reference".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
auto b3 = f.get_b1_ref();
```

the deduced type will *not* be a reference, only the base type `bitset<4>`. This means `b3` is not a reference, and all modifications of `b3` or its contents will be limited to the `b3` object itself.

To get a reference you need to explicitly use `&` in the declaration:

```
auto& b3 = f.get_b1_ref();
```

Comment: Thanks very much. As for Q2, I'm a bit confused by the statement in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/reference. "standard C++ types (like references and pointers) are not built with enough precision to specify individual bits". . Does it mean it is not possible to use regular reference with operator [] to modify individual bit in a bitset? but obviously, in contrast, it can be done in the code snippet. I'm not sure what it means by "not enough precision"

Comment: @ZuckerReis The least addressable unit on computers is the byte. Using a *normal* reference or a pointer you can easily reference or point to a single byte (this is really what `char*` is typically doing, point to a single byte). You can't reference or point to a single bit, which is why `std::bitset::reference` is a type (a class) which uses operator overloading to behave like it's a reference to a single bit in the bitset.

Comment: Thanks very much. It rings a bell... I'm actually using the overloaded operator [] to operate bitwisely on that bitset. 'std::bitset::reference' is the helper class in this case.